# Programming with MS Exchange 2007

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am new to programming in Exchange space.

I would like to develop exchange plugin in c#. this plugin should be able to get all the messages (messages for all email ids) and depending on some rules plugin should able to do some operation on message.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 2):

I hope these links will helps you on programming with MS Exchange 2007 with c#

[Part 1: programming with MS Exchange 2007](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/Exchange2007EWS-Part1.aspx)

[Part 2: programming with MS Exchange 2007](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/EWSPart2.aspx)

[Part 3: programming with MS Exchange 2007](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/EWSPart3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the Developer Center for Exchange on msdn.microsoft.com.

If you want to process messages as they're traveling between mailboxes, you want to look into creating a [Transport Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd877026%28EXCHG.140%29).

However, if you want to look at messages at rest, in a mailbox (or a set of mailboxes), you want to look at Exchange Web Services (supported in Exchange 2007 and up).

However, istead of writing against the EWS SOAP API directly (which can be cumbersome), your best bet is to use the EWS Managed API, which essentially a wrapper for the SOAP API that you can call directly from C#, and it makes looking at mailbox content (and other cool stuff) really easy from C#.

[EWS Managed API Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd633710)

Answer (score 0):

To process all messages that flow through Exchange you should create a transport agent (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012.aspx).